# Gist vs repository on GitHub

Tags: git, repository, github

Say you have a couple of projects that you want to host on GitHub, and they're all pretty small (i.e. each one is a single bash script with less than 100 lines).

Even though they're relatively small, they can still be complex in that size, and a gist seems inappropriate. On the other hand, making an entire repository for a single file seems a bit much, is it? At what point should a gist become a repository, if ever?

You could also just collect all the scripts in one repository, but that'd be messing a lot of stuff that has no relation between them.

I've searched and thought about this problem, but have not found a satisfactory answer.

Comment: I think this is a valid question.  For example, I have two related files, an implementation and a file for testing the implementation.  The concepts in the implementation are more suited for a gist (IMHO), but there is the test file as well that is related.  Does this imply that it should be repository instead of a gist?

Comment: This question was closed because it may not have an objective answer. Nevertheless, I do think that it's constructive. Some googling leads to this discussion on the topic: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/2be87f/github_deciding_when_to_use_a_gist_vs_a_regular/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the set of scripts evolves together/are used together/have *some* kind of relationship (apart from "I wrote the bunch"), create a single repository for them. If not, slice and dice as appropiate. `git` is quite lightweight.

Comment: But should I separate them as whole repositories for a single file? I know that in practice it won't be that much of a diference storage-wise, but isn't it one of those “kill a fly with a bazooka” situations? Would a gist be more appropriate? Why or why not?

Comment: It is your call, at the end. If they are yours only, one repository is fine.